# What's the difference between the Safari iOS cookie settings?

Tags: ios, settings, mobile-safari, cookies

On mobile Safari there are 4 settings for cookies:

1. Always block
2. Allow from current website only
3. Allow from websites I visit
4. Always allow

#1 makes sense but I am unable to distinguish the 3 remaining options.

Other browsers have settings to allow all cookies (could be #3 or #4 above) or only from the current website (eg on example.com don't allow cookies from thirdparty.com; could be #2 or #3 above).

So what is the third behaviour? And which option is which?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Safari for Mac Documentation](https://help.apple.com/safari/mac/8.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj%23sfri11471#/sfri11471) has a good explanation of these settings. They apply to iOS Safari cookies settings, too.

- **Always Block** - Block all first-party cookies and block all third-party cookies.
- **Allow from Current Website Only** - Allow all first-party cookies and block all third-party cookies.
- **Allow from Websites I Visit** - Allow all first-party cookies and block all third-party cookies unless that third party was a first party at one time (based on current cookies and browsing history).
- **Always Allow** - Allow all first-party cookies and allow all third-party cookies.

Comment: "Cookies are deleted after navigating away" -- which cookies? Until recently I had that option selected and cookies weren't deleted.

Comment: Looking at your link, options 2 &3 are not what you've written here. The two descriptions on the link sound identical.

Comment: This website seems to agree with me: http://cookies.how/en/safari-for-iphone But you're right, Apple's documentation is vague. But maybe we're all wrong! I'll see if I can find some more definitive information.

Comment: Okay, this other site has an explanation that I think makes the most sense. https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-cookies/safari-ipad I'll update my answer to reflect this explanation.

Comment: Since iOS 11.0.3 update, the Cookies Allow from current website option has been removed. What is worse, when you There are only two options - Block all cookies or Unblock cookies but when you go back to Block all cookies all open open websites are deleted which is inconvenient and annoying when you want to keep them still open till later.